# How to convert a prototype jquery function to javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a crossword in jquery and for some reason i need to convert it to javascript and avoid using jquery.
I have managed to convert many parts of it but i have a big problem in a prototype function and i cant understand how to convert it.

Here is the code in summary :

```
$("#"+cw_id).crossword();

(function($) {
// plugin definition
$.fn.crossword = function(options) {
    .....
    // implementation code goes here.    
    return this.each(function(){
      ....
    }
})();
// end plugin definition
```

I have tried doing this and similar to this calls but nothing is working fine.

```
document.getElementById("#"+cw_id).crossword();
(function() {
// plugin definition
Object.prototype.crossword = function(options) {

})();
// end plugin definition
```

The actual code of this prototype function is at this link:
https://github.com/electricg/jQuery-Html5-Crossword/blob/master/crossword.js#L1

and the caller is at the index link:
https://github.com/electricg/jQuery-Html5-Crossword/blob/master/index.html#L62

I really need to know how to convert this prototype function back to javascript 
Thank you in advance for any help provided

Comment: If you want to replace `$("#"+cw_id).crossword();` with `document.querySelector("#"+cw_id).crossword();`, you have to extend the `Element` or `HTMLElement` prototype instead of `Object`. Anyways, extending native prototypes is usually no longer a good solution, so I would prefer that you use a normal function: `crossword(document.querySelector("#"+cw_id));` PS: this is one of those JQuery thingies that screams for a rewrite, since rerendering a 2D array will be way easier and shorter than doing all those node manipulations.

Comment: You would be better off not trying to make it follow jQuery's plugin pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For similar functionality to jQuery, you're looking for `HTMLElement.prototype`.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.crossword = function(text) {
  this.innerHTML = text;
};

document.getElementById('crossword1').crossword('crossword here');
```

```html
<div id=crossword1 />
```

[Since that's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice), I would use a function and bind the element to get a similar result. You can also pass it in as an argument, but that would require more refactoring of the existing code.

```js
const crossword = function(text) {
  this.innerHTML = text;
};

crossword.bind(document.getElementById('crossword1'))('crossword here');
```

```html
<div id=crossword1 />
```

Comment: personally I would pass in the element reference and not worry about this to simplify it.

`function crossword(element, options)`

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and answers, i am on my way to make some tests since the best way is to avoid doing a direct convertion and go with the similar way which seems nice.